# Pipelined Radix-2 DIF FFT SDF Architecture

Tags: vhdl, fft

I want to implement Radix-2 Single-path Delay Feedback (SDF) Decimation-In-Frequency FFT with Pipelining in VHDL.
I am trying to understand the below architecture as described in this [MIT OpenCourseWare Lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-973-communication-system-design-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture_10.pdf)

[image]

Since its a DIF FFT, shouldn't the upper half of the data be directly passed on to next stage without requiring multiplication with twiddle factor? Is there a multiplexer which controls multiplication and not shown in the diagram? Can anyone please elaborate on this architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, the upper half of each stage doesn't require multiplication. However, the way to implement "no multiplication" is not describe in your schematic.

As I understand it, data is serialized in and out of each stage, which is hinted by the comment that multipliers are at 50% utilization.

It seems dubious that you would reuse these multipliers for anything else. In that case, I would think it makes more sense to multiply by 1 the upper half than add a mux with matching delays.

Comment: that makes sense :) My follow up question then is how does the multiplier / CORDIC rotator know when to multiply by 1

Comment: When to multiply by 1 can be decided based on a counter, when data is streamed to next stage from the BF (sum), multiply by 1 and when data is streamed to next stage from delay element (SR/FIFO), multiply by appropriate twiddle factor

Comment: Yes, you need some control logic to store the 8/4/2 input signal values and then output them two at a time. That block could output the twiddles as well and the "multiplier" would perform (a ± b)*W^n_N

Comment: I was finally able to implement this in VHDL. I had to make the adder and multiplier blocks asynchronous so as the output is ready to be latched to next stage FIFO on next clock cycle. Not sure if that is the way to go.

Comment: This is definitely not the way to go. You usually need 2-3 pipeline delays to have a single multiplication at a decent frequency. You need to delay your control signals to match datapath delays. Adding delays will improve maximum frequency and have no impact on throughput. On FPGA, it is virtually free (since most slice has unused registers) and will only cost latency. Latency rarely matters, a thousand delays at 100MHz is still only 10 microseconds

Comment: I thought so. But, since I read that the first output of FFT is ready on (N-1)th clock and since I am using only a single clock throughout, I made it asynchronous. How do I initiate the multiplication on clock edge and ignore the next 2 cycles? Use an internal counter? Any sample you could link to?